# OrdinalClassification in RWeka

Tags: r, package, rweka

I saw that there are a lot of meta classifiers of Weka implemented in RWeka package but I can't find the meta classifiers OrdinalClassifiers. Is there a package that I can use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can install the package `ordinalClassClassifier`. To do so, start from the GUI Chooser and select the Package Manager.

[image: GUI Chooser]

Then scroll down to find `ordinalClassClassifier` (Note that the packages are alphabetized with lower case and uppercase separately) and click on `Install`

[image: Package Selection and Installation]